# FULLTEXT Index fails to return result in MySQL

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a `FULLTEXT` index on a `VARCHAR` column. I search for content in this column as such:

```
SELECT ID, NAME 
FROM people 
WHERE MATCH(people.NAME) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

To my parameter I would for instance bind this value: `+firstname* +lastname*` - and in most cases this will return expected results. However, in edge cases I don't understand, this fails to match. Take this example:

The name in the column is `Liliana De Lima`. If I bind this value: `+liliana*` it will find the row. If I bind this value: `+liliana* +d*` it does not. Why?

Normally I have no problems binding multiple words with the above logic. For instance, binding the value `+peter* +p*` will return a result for the name `Peter Prip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe "De" is too short so +d* will not match it.
Maybe look at modifying ft_min_word_len parameter.